# How to edit go.js group templates of basic charts?

Tags: javascript, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs, gojs

I want to create a Directed Acyclic Graph as shown in image 2. I'm using **go.js basic charts**. But after setting `nodedataarray` and `linkdatarray`, it outputs as in image 1. To generate the graph in image 2, I want two things to be done.

**1. Display node templates horizontally in a group template.**

**2. Set levels(positions) for group templates.**

I read examples given on the web site and I couldn't find a way. Please help me to solve above two problems.

---

### image 1

[image: image 1]

### image 2

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the **Diagram.layout** to be a **LayeredDigraphLayout** and the **Group.layout** to be a **GridLayout**.

The **Diagram** could be set up with:

```
  $(go.Diagram, "myDiagramDiv",element
    {
      layout:
        $(go.LayeredDigraphLayout,
          { direction: 90, layerSpacing: 50 }),
      . . .
    });
```

The **Group** template could be something like:

```
$(go.Group, go.Panel.Vertical,
    {
      layout: $(go.GridLayout, { wrappingColumn: 4 }),
      . . .
    },
    $(go.TextBlock, . . .),
    $(go.Panel, "Auto",
      $(go.Shape, . . .),
      $(go.Placeholder, . . .)
    )
);
```